# Distribution on $(0, \infty)$ is not a restriction of another distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Given the linear form
$$
\langle u, \phi\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \partial^k \phi(1/k)
$$
which is a distribution on $(0, \infty)$, show that there is no $v \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$ whose restriction to $(0, \infty)$ equals $u$.

This question is similar to [On the extension of distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462571/on-the-extension-of-distribution?rq=1) but I didn't understand that solution and I'm wondering if there is an argument that involves making a partition of unity.

My attempt so far:

For any test function $\phi \in C_0^\infty((0, 
\infty))$, for some $N$, $\operatorname{supp} (\phi) \subset (\frac{1}{N}, \infty)$.  So,

$$\left|\langle u, \phi\rangle\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N+1} \left|\partial^k \phi(1/k)\right|.$$

Using that estimate it is not hard to show that $u \in \mathscr{D}((0, \infty))$.  Suppose $v$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ that restricts to $u$ on $(0,
\infty)$.  Let $\rho$ be a test function identically equal to 1 on $[-1, 1]$ and support in a small neighborhood of that set. For all $n$, let $\mathbb{O_n} = \{(-2, \frac{1}{n-1}), (\frac{1}{n}, 2)\}$ and let $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ be the partition of unity of $supp(\rho e^x)$ with respect to $\mathbb{O_n}$.  Then 
$$\langle v, \rho e^x\rangle  = \langle v, \psi_1 \rho e^x\rangle  +\langle v, \psi_2 \rho e^x\rangle  = \langle v, \psi_1 \rho e^x\rangle  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} e^{1/k}.$$

The last sum goes off to infinity as $n \to \infty$, but that doesn't finish the problem and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You idea is correct - just take any test function which behaves like $\exp(x)$ on the interval $(-1, 1)$ and then look at what happens when you try to apply the distribution $u$ to this test function.